# File Stream file saving

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an image file in Canvas element that I get in code behind in asp.net. now I want to save it to a folder in my project but file stream always saves it to c drive. What do I do?

```cs
[WebMethod()]
public void SaveUser(string imageData)
{
    //Create image to local machine.
    string fileNameWitPath = path + "4200020789506" + ".png";

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
    // Save fileNameWitPath variable to Database.
}
```

Comment: Does `path` have a value?

Comment: yes path has a value that points to C:\Demo folder

Comment: Is it `C:\Demo` or `C:\Demo\ `? That could be the reason why you save directly to C:

Comment: its @"C:\Demo\" i want to save it in img folder which is in my visual studio project folder moreover if i pass a value saved in string variable instead of directly passing "4200020789506" it gives no error but doesnot save the image either :OOOOOOOO

Comment: You might want to take a look at the `Server.MapPath` method mentioned in the answers below (just don't use fileNameWitPath for that, just the filename)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I do and it works well. For you, filePath/filename = fileNameWitPath. Do this for each file you have. Hope it works for you. If you need further info, Id be glad to help.

```
 using (var stream = File.Create(filePath + filename))
 {
       attachment.ContentObject.DecodeTo(stream, cancel.Token);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how I save files to an `Images` folder in my project directory.

```
var fileName = "4200020789506.png";
var base64String = SOME_REALLY_LONG_STRING;

using (var s = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)))
using (var f = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    s.CopyTo(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine your `path` variable points to your C:\ drive.

You need to set the path variable equal to the location you want, for instance:

```
public void SaveUser(string imageData)
    {
        path = @"C:\YourCustomFolder\";  // your path needs to point to the Directory you want to save
        //Create image to local machine.
        string fileNameWitPath = path + "4200020789506" + ".png";

        //chekc if directory exist, if not, create
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
                bw.Write(data);
                bw.Close();
            }
        }
        // Save fileNameWitPath variable to Database.
    }
```

I also included a Check to see if your directory exists, and if it does not, it will create a folder called 'YourCustomFolder' on your C drive, where it will save images.

If you would like to save your image to a folder in your project, I would recommend using `Server.MapPath(~/YourFolderInApplication)`